# Spring security is interfering with actuator endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security in my microservice application, I also have actuator endpoint in place. Whenever I try to deploy my microservice and access the /actuator/prometheus URL it shows me the dialog box to enter Username and password. I want this to remove .

Comment: It is not interfering, it is by design and documented in the Spring Boot documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html) (section named "Security")

> If you deploy applications behind a firewall, you may prefer that all
> your actuator endpoints can be accessed without requiring
> authentication. You can do so by changing the
> management.endpoints.web.exposure.include property, as follows:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Comment: It is not helping